# How did I accidentally summon this helpful Finder search feature, and what is it called?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

In MacOS Catalina (10.15.7) I somehow inadvertently turned on this very nice search feature in a Finder window.

I can select several search criteria in pulldown menus and build a search via GUI rather than by typing. In some cases this may be more convenient for me.

**Question:** How did I accidentally summon this helpful Finder search feature? I'd like to use it again! And what is it called?

[image: pulldown GUI helpful search feature in a Finder window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command F in the Finder brings up this window. It's also under File > Find.

Finder Preferences has a setting for the scope of the search: the current folder, "This Mac", or whatever you used last time.

Comment: Yes this is even more likely what happened; I was copy/pasting files from one finder window to another using Command C and V, and F is directly above them. This is definitely how I'll access this in the future.

Answer (score 5):

That is the advanced search tool for finder to perform spotlight searches. Look for a + where you have save and - buttons currently on the finder window.

[image]

It’s described in the “get to know Finder” article.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201732

> In both Spotlight and Finder, you can [use advanced searches to narrow your search results.](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/narrow-search-results-mh15155/mac)

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/narrow-search-results-mh15155/mac

Comment: yes, people are frequently amazed to find that I've asked exactly the question to which I'd like an answer.

Comment: This is a great reason why multi part questions can sometimes not get all the answers you might hope for. Especially “guess what I did” type questions. Hope your all sorted now.

Comment: You mean because people don't take the time to read the title before answering? Or when I repeat it again almost verbatim in the body with "Question:" in bold font? I really don't see it happening on any other SE site, and I have some experience asking in many of them.